# Reducing downtime during Updates installation SharePoint

Tags: upgrade

How can we provide a PowerShell script to reduce downtime during Cumulative Updates installation SharePoint 2010 and 2013. I've already read this article:
[Why SharePoint 2013 Cumulative Update takes 5 hours to install?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2013/04/01/why-sharepoint-2013-cumulative-update-takes-5-hours-to-install.aspx)
 but I still need some more experience around it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you already go through the best practice. I can share you my experience, which may help you. One thing is, we cannot avoid the down time rather we can minimize.

Down time depend upon couple of things.

- how often you patching your farm, if it is 2 or 3 CUs Old then it will be quick but if it is more than that or You are applying SP then it requires time.
- Hardware on the SharePoint servers
- Number of sharepoint servers
- Amount of Data in SharePoint Farm, Number of Web Apps, Site collections etc.

In one of my farm i am doing this way to reduce the down time.

- start the App Server first
- I take out WFE from Load balancer, one by one. apply the patch then move to next.
- after this, i ran the upgrade-spscontentDatabase against the each content DB, i ran multiple powershell(4) on server to upgrade 4 dbs at the same time.
- Now i ran the Config wizard on central admin.
- Again taking one server out from LB and run the config wizard.

But i do this in one of small but imp farm. On other sharepoint i book 4 to 6 hours down time on non-prod hour. Usually on weekends.

Comment: what if I detach all content databases and install binaries and then run config wizard during weekend and attach content databases one at the time during weekday night and update them one by one.

Comment: If u detach content db then it is down time for the sharepoint.....all site collections reside in content database